# Using C# Winforms with Win32

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I'm new to Win32 and not super familiar with C#, so bear with me please. I have a project in school that involves making an audio editing program, and we were given a choice of which language to use. I decided to thrust myself into unfamiliarity by going with a combination of C# and Win32.

My progress so far in this is creating a Winforms project, scrapping all the Winforms code, and creating a window using the Win32 API. I do not know how to manipulate the window using Winforms or use anything else from the .NET framework in a meaningful way.

My question is, is there some way to take a window created using the Win32 API and edit it using Winforms? Like, pass the window handle to my Form, edit it, and see the changes reflected in the window that has been created? Let me know if this doesn't make sense. It's been difficult for me to find much documentation on this, but maybe I'm just searching in the wrong places. If you could let me know of any resources that might help, or provide a nudge in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Winforms with the WinAPI? What kind of combination is that? That's really a strange idea. If you want to use the WinAPI do so in a C++ project and don't use .NET at all. If you want to use .NET use it completely.

Comment: Why not use C# + Winforms + NAudio instead of trying to force Win32 with C# and Winforms ? or maybe try C++/Cli if you're more familiar with C++ ?

Comment: I would like to help, but I can't imagine why would you want to do this. Why not just use WinForms forms, which are afterall just Win32 windows underneath? Is it just because you are not experienced with WinForms? If so, I think it is easier to learn WinForms, then solve all the issues of integrating these things. Otherwise you can stick with plain Win32 development in C++, with help of something like WTL or maybe even MFC.

Comment: I think that I just had it backwards, it makes much more sense now. The reason that I wanted to do this is so that I could learn about how Winforms interacts with the winapi and so that I could have greater control over the window if I needed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are doing it backwards. The basic idea in winforms is to keep the majority of your code managed and then [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) your way to the native API only where necessary.

There are a number of books that you [can get for free](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/05/free-e-books-on-c.php) to get you started with C#.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense actually. I feel silly for trying to do it the other way now...

Answer (score 0):

Windows Form from Window Handle, `hWnd` is handle as `IntPtr`

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;
(Form)Control.FromHandle(hWnd)
```